# Windows hang instead of waking up from standby

Tags: windows-7, freeze, standby

My System is Windows 7 Ultimate on a Shuttle SP35P2 Pro Barebone. Everything worked nicely, even entering standby and resuming from it.

Yesterday I installed a new graphic adapter (XFX HD5750), removed the old drivers completely, installed the latest XFX drivers.

Since then resuming from standby does not work anymore. After standby I need to switch the computer off the hard way, and sometimes it won't even boot directly afterwards, just shows a black screen. After some time it will boot again.

Any ideas what causes this to happen?

Comment: This sounds like it should belong on superuser.com

Comment: Oops, sorry I thought I had asked on superuser - my mistake!

Comment: By only reading the title, my answer is "A 3rd-party driver has a bug. Get rid of the driver and/or device".  Reading the question confirms this diagnosis. There is a bug in a 3rd party driver that doesn't handle the system being powered down. i'm surprised that nVidia has a bug that nasty in it's drivers; usually only ATI writes drivers that bad - oh wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb, when you change something and the behavior of your system changes, it probably has to do with what you changed. Try reverting your system back to the way it was before and see if the problem persists. Did you make contact with the motherboard? Were you properly grounded? Did you properly handle the video card? A lot of people may think these precautions are not necessary, but static really can do damage.